# Docker buildx - No such file or directory on arm64 platform

Tags: docker, dockerfile, arm64, buildx

I want to rebuild a docker image to add [support arm64v8 architecture](https://github.com/ahobsonsayers/DockURSim/issues/4), for the image [arranhs/duckerursim](https://hub.docker.com/r/arranhs/dockursim), by using [buildx](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/multi-arch/).

After executing the build command

```
docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64,linux/arm/v8 -t my-user/my-repository:latest --push .
```

I get this error:

```
 => ERROR [linux/arm64 11/26] RUN mv /tmp/ursim* /tmp/ursim                                                                                                                                            0.0s
------
 > [linux/arm64 11/26] RUN mv /tmp/ursim* /tmp/ursim:
#45 0.036 mv: cannot stat '/tmp/ursim*': No such file or directory
------
Dockerfile:43
--------------------
  41 |     RUN rm /tmp/URSim-Linux.tar.gz
  42 |      # Rename the URSim folder to jus ursim
  43 | >>> RUN mv /tmp/ursim* /tmp/ursim
  44 |     
  45 |     RUN echo "**** Installing URSim ****"
--------------------
error: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c mv /tmp/ursim* /tmp/ursim" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

It seems like the directory and files in the previous steps has not been created? Any idea why?

I tried the docker image already on an ubuntu machine (which uses linux/amd64 i guess), where the image works fine. But I want to work on a Macbook that works with the Apple m1 chip.

**Dockerfile**

```
1   FROM lsiobase/guacgui:latest
2   
3   # Set Version Information
4   ARG BUILD_DATE="10/07/20"
5   ARG VERSION="5.8.2.10297"
6   LABEL build_version="URSim Version: ${VERSION} Build Date: ${BUILD_DATE}"
7   LABEL maintainer="Arran Hobson Sayers"
8   LABEL MAINTAINER="Arran Hobson Sayers"
9   ENV APPNAME="URSim"
10  
11  # Set Timezone
12  ARG TZ="Europe/London"
13  ENV TZ ${TZ}
14  
15  # Setup Environment
16  ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
17  
18  # Set Home Directory
19  ENV HOME /ursim
20  
21  # Set robot model - Can be UR3, UR5 or UR10
22  ENV ROBOT_MODEL UR5
23  
24  RUN echo "**** Installing Dependencies ****"
25  RUN apt-get update
26  RUN apt-get install -qy --no-install-recommends openjdk-8-jre psmisc
27   # Change java alternatives so we use openjdk8 (required by URSim) not openjdk11 that comes with guacgui
28  RUN update-alternatives --config java
29  #RUN update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java 10000
30  
31  # Setup JAVA_HOME
32  ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
33  
34  RUN echo "**** Downloading URSim ****"
35   # Download URSim Linux tar.gz
36  RUN curl https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/ur-support-site/71480/URSim_Linux-5.8.2.10297.tar.gz -o /tmp/URSim-Linux.tar.gz
37   # Extract tarball
38  RUN cd /tmp/
39  RUN tar xvzf /tmp/URSim-Linux.tar.gz
40   #Remove the tarball
41  RUN rm /tmp/URSim-Linux.tar.gz
42   # Rename the URSim folder to jus ursim
43  RUN mv /tmp/ursim* /tmp/ursim #??WHY IT DOENST WORK??
44  
45  RUN echo "**** Installing URSim ****"
46   # cd to ursim folder
47  RUN cd /tmp/ursim
48   # Make URControl and all sh files executable
49  RUN chmod +x ./*.sh ./URControl
50   # Stop install of unnecessary packages and install required ones quietly
51  RUN sed -i 's|apt-get -y install|apt-get -qy install --no-install-recommends|g' ./install.sh
52   # Skip xterm command. We dont have a desktop
53  RUN sed -i 's|tty -s|(exit 0)|g' install.sh
54   # Skip Check of Java Version as we have the correct installed and the command will fail
55  RUN sed -i 's|needToInstallJava$|(exit 0)|g' install.sh
56   # Skip install of desktop shortcuts - we dont have a desktop
57  RUN sed -i '/for TYPE in UR3 UR5 UR10/,$ d' ./install.sh
58   # Remove commands that are not relevant on docker as we are root user
59  RUN sed -i 's|pkexec ||g' ./install.sh
60  RUN sed -i 's|sudo ||g' ./install.sh
61  RUN sed -i 's|sudo ||g' ./ursim-certificate-check.sh
62  
63   # Install URSim
64  RUN ./install.sh
65  RUN echo "Installed URSim"
66  
67  RUN echo "**** Clean Up ****"
68  RUN rm -rf /tmp/* /var/lib/apt/lists/* /var/tmp/*
69  
70  # Copy ursim run service script
71  COPY ursim /etc/services.d/ursim
72  
73  # Expose ports 
74  # Guacamole web browser viewer
75  EXPOSE 8080
76  # VNC viewer
77  EXPOSE 3389
78  # Modbus Port
79  EXPOSE 502
80  # Interface Ports
81  EXPOSE 29999
82  EXPOSE 30001-30004
83  
84  # Mount Volumes
85  VOLUME /ursim
86  
87  ENTRYPOINT ["/init"]
```

**Builder**

I created the builder like this:

```
# Init
docker run --rm --privileged multiarch/qemu-user-static --reset -p yes

# Create a builder
docker buildx create --name mybuilder --driver docker-container

# Switch to builder and checkout
docker buildx use mybuilder
docker buildx inspect --bootstrap
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinitialization is required after restarting the machine

Init:

```
docker run --rm --privileged multiarch/qemu-user-static --reset -p yes
```

Answer (score 0):

`RUN cd /tmp/`  is not the correct way to switch the working directory in dockerfile and will only switch it for the current command. You need `WORKDIR /tmp`

Comment: or `RUN cd /tmp && tar xvzf /tmp/URSim-Linux.tar.gz`